# R use shinyFiles to get a path name that I can use in a function

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building an RShiny App and I'd like to have users be able to navigate to a directory and then I want to be able to use this directory name in a function. There are several similar questions out there, but nothing I've been able to work out for my problem. I created a simple reproducible example.

In this example, I'd like to be able to take the `path_prefix` and pass it to a system command so that I can change to this directory. I'm having the function print the `path_prefix` in the Shiny window and what is printed is appropriate. However, the functions I'm using turn the path into a list where each folder is in quotes. Does anyone have suggestions for how this could work?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton('path_prefix', 'Select a directory', title='Select a directory'),
  textOutput('path_prefix'),
  actionButton("run", "run test")
)
# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  volumes <- getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'path_prefix', roots=volumes, session=session)
  dirname <- reactive({parseDirPath(volumes, input$path_prefix)})


  # Observe input dir
  observe({
    #fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$path_prefix)
    if(!is.null(dirname)){
      print(dirname())
      output$path_prefix <- renderText(dirname())
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    system(paste0("cd ", input$path_prefix))
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In your `observeEvent` function, did you want `dirname()` instead of `input$path_prefix`?

Comment: Thank you @Ben. That worked. It also works if I put `parseDirPath(volumes, input$path_prefix)` there, which is the same thing without the `reactive` component.